# choosing between declarative_authorization and cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan, declarative-authorization

What is the difference between CanCan and declarative_authorization,
and How can I choose between this two?
Could you please provide some examples in which one of them would be a better choice?

I just find a link :https://gist.github.com/236709
but I don't see any big difference there

Comment: I haven't ever used declarative-authorization, but viewing the railscasts.com videos on each of them might give you a better idea of the differences.

Comment: @bdares I have watched both episode of them, but still cannot figure out how to choose between...Lol